# How can the order of inherited includes be controlled in vsprops Property Sheets?

Tags: c++, vsprops

I'm using some vsprops sheets that inherit from each other. My base property sheet defines some include paths. In a second vsprops file that inherits from it, I want to add some more include paths.

However, I want to be able to choose whether the additional include paths come before or after the base include paths. I'm sure I've seen something like an $(Inherits) variable that can be used to do this, but I can't remember what it was or find it again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it now:

$(Inherit) is what I want, as in this example:

```
c:\test2;$(Inherit);c:\mystuff
```

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx1tt59t(VS.80).aspx